# How do I get to the vista on Moorwatch Tower?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Diessa Plateau there is a vista on top of a tower called Moorwatch Tower, which is standing on a hill with no visible method of getting on top of it.

[image]

How do I get on top of the Moorwatch Tower to get the vista?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speaking to the people around the tower, you get some conversations about flying cows and harpies.

There is a harpy nest to the immediate south east and further south east than that there is a guy called called Mad Mardine, who is catapulting cows into the air.

While there are no events going on (him catapulting cows *is* an event in itself), you can use his catapult to throw yourself to the top of the tower;

[image]

From here you can easily get the vista, and then use the 'gate' in the top of the tower to get back down to the bottom.

Apparently this isn't the only way to do this, although the other methods are essentially 'ending the current event', making the catapult active for you to interact with.